# Prepaid SIM for a week in the USA

Tags: usa, cellphones

I'm looking for the cheapest possible plan, that will allow me to receive calls and  will have a small amount of data, 1gb max. All the prepaid plans I found seem to be at least 30$+taxes.

Where i live you used to be able to buy a SIM card with 1gb of data for an equivalent of maybe 1-2$ that would allow you to receive calls for a couple of weeks and then either You throw it away or pay some money to continue using it.

Is there something similar available in the USA? (Chicago area if relevant)

Comment: This might be hard to find. US prepaid mobile is mostly designed for locals rather than travelers. You might see what's available at shops in O'Hare. Also consider getting a USA coverage plan from your existing mobile carrier, if they offer one.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, there is no service which will provide you 1gb with calls/text at your expected price point. And as Michael commented on the question, you cannot purchase a US prepaid sim from US networks as they ask your SSN in most of the cases. You have to find someone living in the US and has a valid SSN to get you a prepaid sim under their name.

Apart from that, there are some very good international sim's which you can purchase with data and unlimited calls/text for your travel purpose like Lyca Mobile, Vodafone and others. But they charge you minimum of $25 to $30.

The best option would be to check with your existing carrier in your country if they offer you international roaming plans.

Comment: I think you're mistaken about the need of a SSN in the United States. I've never heard of or experienced demand for an SSN; this recent article in a well-respective travel website also makes no mention of it. https://toomanyadapters.com/buying-sim-card-usa/

Comment: I am not really sure about that. Because of the security reasons, lately they have been asking SSN and are not giving sim cards to international travelers especially AT&T. I am not really sure about the other networks. One of my friends recently (August 2019) faced this challenge and a family member took care of her with his SSN. And I experienced this when I came to the States on vacation back in 2013 when my cousin had to buy a prepaid sim from AT&T for me.

Comment: I bought a T-mobile SIM from a Best Buy in May 2019, no questions were asked. Registration was done online without any problems for me as a foreigner.

Comment: @Anders that’s cool :)